# Copy files between s3 Buckets with destination bucket having a directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have two s3 buckets. I want to copy a file from Bucket `from` to Bucket `to`. In Bucket `to`, I have a folder `/copy_here`. When I tried to directly copy the contents between the buckets using Boto it works. But when I want to copy this to a directory in the destination, I am getting `ParameterValidationError`. Here is the code which I tried to execute:

```py
def copyToBucket(fromBucket, toBucket, fileName):
    copySource = {
        'Bucket': readBucketName,
        'Key': fileName
    }
    uploadBucket = s3.Bucket(uploadBucketName)
    uploadBucket.copy(copySource, fileName)
```

I looked upon s3 meta client and that offers the same functionality as well. I am not sure if this operation is possible in a single step. If there is any, that would be great. If not, should I copy initially to the destination bucket and move my file to the `copy_here` folder? Currently, my `uploadBucketName` has been set to `to/copy_here`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders and directories do not exist in Amazon S3. Instead, the filename (`Key`) of an object consists of the **full path plus filename**. (Well, the S3 management console makes it *appear* that there are folders, but they don't really exist.)

So, this would copy a file as you desire:

```py
import boto3

copySource = {
    'Bucket': 'source-bucket-name',
    'Key': 'foo.txt'
}
uploadBucket = s3.Bucket('destination-bucket-name')
uploadBucket.copy(copySource, 'copy_here/foo.txt')
```

Note that the destination `Key` consists of the path + filename. The bucket name must consist only of the bucket name itself.